# How can I sort a list of titles alphabetically, ignoring "The", using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of titles that I am pulling from the database sorted alphabetically ie:

```
[
  'Morning Glory',
  'Red',
  'Skyline',
  'The Next Three Days'
]
```

What would be the best way to re-sort this list of titles ignoring "The" so that it would become:

```
[
  'Morning Glory',
  'The Next Three Days',
  'Red',
  'Skyline'
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
titles = ["Morning Glory", "Red", "Skyline", "The Next Three Days"]
titles.sort_by {|w| w.sub(/^the /i,"")}
=> ["Morning Glory", "The Next Three Days", "Red", "Skyline"]
```

Comment: Without the edit, I wouldn't be able to read the whole thing without scrolling.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It fit OK on my screen. Browser/font difference or something. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: seems like this would be a great feature to have built into rails

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use a custom comparator for sorting.

Refer to: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_using_a_custom_comparator#Ruby

Comment: +1. this. Custom sorting is almost always implemented using a custom comparator, regardless of the programming language.