# Sort list alphabetically ignoring "the"

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sorting, alphabetical

I've a feeling that there's no simple answer to this Q, but here goes anyway. I'm using Codeigniter with MySQL. I pull a list of resource titles from the database with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM resource ORDER BY title ASC
```

and want to sort them alphabetically ignoring "the" at the start. Something like (from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251742/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-titles-alphabetically-ignoring-the-using-ruby)):

- Aardvark
- Beetle
- Dragon
- The coypu

to appear as:

- Aardvark
- Beetle
- The coypu
- Dragon

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087603/mysql-sort-alphabetically-but-ignore-the) suggested some messy SQL which might be a possibility, but I'd like to get a generic algorithm for this which I could apply in all projects as this is a common problem.

If there's no simple answer then it's not important - it's just a 'grace note' for my users :)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
order by (case when title like 'The %' then substring(title, 5, 1000) else title end)
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, that cracks it. I'm not very familiar with SQL functions, just using a few now and again, but a look at the MySQL manual under functions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions.html) enables me to understand what you've done. Pretty simple when you know how :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a duplicate column for 'title' and then remove all 'the' from that column.

First update the table to duplicate the 'title' column

```
ALTER TABLE resource
ADD title_less_the varchar(50) (same as title)

UPDATE resource
SET title_less_the = title

update resource (
set title_less_the = replace(title_less_the, 'the ', '')
```

Then when you search something like this leaving out the column that has been modified:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM resource
ORDER BY title_less_the ASC
```